# Is every buffer in GPU memory always a minimal alignment of 64 KB in DirectX12 for all different allocation methods?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, memory-alignment, directx-12

So I am trying to save some bytes in my VRAM usage and one thing I have seen is that every [PlacedResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createplacedresource) for a buffer (vertex or index or any other kind of resource buffer) must be 64 KB aligned (correct me if I am wrong, also I know textures can be 4 KB aligned in placed resources, but not regular mesh buffers meaning every single buffer must take up a whole 64 KB. So for a single mesh, it takes up a minimum of 128 KB since that memory can't be used for other meshes at the same time without freeing the resource or overwriting the resource). Which for certain meshes can waste a lot of memory.

Does [CommittedResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createcommittedresource) and [ReservedResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createreservedresource) have the same alignment requirements? Or do they get a tighter packing in GPU memory? Is it possible to reduce the memory waste overhead in placed resources?

(I understand reserved resources is just Virtual memory range allocations (64 KB alignment requirement too?) and it doesn't mean much until you actual map it to memory, but upon that mapping does each virtual allocation have to be 64 KB aligned for buffers?)

Comment: Resources are going to have the same alignment requirements no matter what method you use to allocate them, it's about the address, not whether the pages were already committed. For buffers you can also pack multiple buffers of the same stride into a single allocation and manipulate the `BaseVertexLocation`, `StartIndexLocation`, and `StartInstanceLocation` parameters when drawing.